# How can I style different sections of the same post differently in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I have a post that's broken up into 2 sections: an intro, and a main list. I'd like each section styled differently. My problem is that I don't know how to create my template file to accommodate multiple sections. For example, this won't work because you can't use the_content() twice like that:

```
<div class="intro">
    <?php the_content(); ?> // intro content only
</div>
<div class="main-list">
    <?php the_content(); ?> // main list content only
</div>
```

How can I specify that some content belongs to one container, and some content belongs to another container?

Comment: Is there some sort of separator inside your post which can be used to split the content?

Comment: Could you elaborate on "some sort of separator"? What would be an example of something like that?

Comment: for example "Read More" WordPress tag or content split on multiple pages by pagination via <!––nextpage––> WP tag